# How take value from Media Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I wolud like to take a value from field "Link to" by php

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function `wp_get_attachment_url(id)`. For example:

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( 55 );
echo $image_url;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns a value from the "URL" field, not "Link to"